# Declare __global object inside kernel

Tags: memory, opencl

I tried to declare a __global memory chunk inside the kernel, like

```
__global float arr[200];
```

I assume this would create an array in the global memory that I could referred to in the kernel. The program compiled successfully, but then 
when I run it, it indicated:

> error: variable with automatic storage duration
>             cannot be stored in the named address space

I don't know why this happen. 
In order to use global memory, did we have to create a buffer on the host side before we use it?

If I want to create an array shared by all the threads, except passing another new argument for this global array, what can I do instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate it in program scope, at least in OpenCL 2.

```
__global float arr[200];
kernel void foo()
{
   if(get_global_id(0) == 0)
     arr[0] = 3;
}
```

Though be careful with initialization of course, there's no way to synchronize the work-items across the dispatch so it is not really practical to initialize it and use it in the same kernel if you have multiple work-groups.

It doesn't really make much sense to allocate it in kernel scope. If the work-groups are serialized, what would the lifetime be of the global array allocated in the kernel code? Should it outlast a workgroup, a dispatch, stay permanently to be shared between that kernel and the next? The obvious might be that it would have the same lifetime as the kernel, but then it would be impossible to initialize and use without a race. If it is persistent across multiple kernels then host allocation or program scope allocation makes more sense.

Why is passing a new argument such a problem?

Comment: Not a problem in fact. Just wonder if there is any way to avoid host-device transfer.

Comment: Ah, well if you are only running once it is always going to do a transfer unless you calculate on the device. If you allocate via the runtime and don't write any data into it then the host->device transfer may be avoided. It's going to have to copy the binary to the device whatever happens, and that binary would contain the data. More likely program scope global variables will be allocated by the driver in roughly the same way as runtime allocated ones anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`__global` memory object can be allocated only via API call on the host side.
You can also use `__local` memory object which can be allocated via API call on the host side as well as inside the kernel and is visible to all threads within the work group.